# Binding .on events with an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I attempted to bind an object of events using a for key in object loop.

```
events = {
   mouseup:function(data){console.log(data)},
   mousedown:function(data){console.log(data)},
}
for (var key in events ) {
            console.log('binding: ' + key) ;
            $('body').on(key ,function(data){
                console.log(key ,data);
            })

}
```

However, the last object (mousedown) gets bound for both events. Could anyone explain why?

Check out the fiddle for a complete example.

https://jsfiddle.net/2439rw4a/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeap - because `key` is not evaluated until the event fires, and by that time it has been overwritten and remains 'mousedown'.

You need to isolate the current value of `key` at the time of binding the event. You have two options:

1) Send it in via an immediately-executed function closure. This captures a local copy of `key` in the scope of the event callback.

```
for (var key in events ) {
    $('.box').on(key, (function(key) { return function(data){
        console.log(key);
    }; })(key));
```

2) Send it in via event data

```
for (var key in events ) {
    $('.box').on(key, {key: key}, function(evt){
        console.log(evt.data.key);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a good example of such bugs type.

You get such behaviour, because `key` in `console.log(key)` is equal to last key in `for` loop.
All works fine, just change console log to show event type, not a `key`:

```
events = {
   mouseup:function(data){console.log(data)},
   mousedown:function(data){console.log(data)},
}
for (var key in events ) {
            console.log('binding: ' + key) ;
            $('.box').on(key ,function(data){
                console.log(event.type);
            })

}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2439rw4a/

Answer (score 0):

By the time the event fires, the value of `key` *is the last key*. The execution of the code is similar to:

```
key = 'mouseup';

$('body').on(...);

key = 'mousedown';

$('body').on(...);

// By this time, key = 'mousedown'
// Mouse is clicked.
// When even fires, it looks for key which by now has the last key
```

Consider using `Object.keys` and `array.forEach`. This way, your handler sees `key` as the value at that iteration, instead of a shared `key` variable.

```
Object.keys(events).forEach(function(key){
  console.log('binding: ' + key) ;
  $('body').on(key ,function(data){
    console.log(key ,data);
  })
});
```